# Content Type in SharePoint Via VB scripting

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, checkin

Whilst I'm trying to checkin the file into SharePoint using VB scripting, I'm being asked to manually select the Content Type (either document or Link to document). Can you please help how can I automate if using any command??

After setting

```
Set wb = workbooks.open("file.xlsx")
Wb.checkin
```

Please note once I choose the type of document it's successfully checking into SP, but have to do it manually all the time.

Many Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Might pay to check your tags, vb scripting and vb.net are quite different beasts

Comment: As Hursey mention, you should be very aware of what technology you are using.